# What's a good way to handle shadowing variables?

Tags: python, functional-programming, graph-theory, naming

What's a good way to handle variables in helper functions that would naturally take the same name as an outer variable? Like here where I’ve added the underscores.

```py
from typing import List, Set, Any, Tuple, Callable

def graph_fold(g: Graph,
               combiner: Callable[[Node_key, List], Any]) -> List:
    """Equivalent to forming a depth-first forest and
    mapping `fold-tree combiner` over
    the trees"""

    def helper(_disc: Set[Node_key], node: Node_key) -> Tuple[Any, Set[Node_key]]:
        _disc.add(node)
        _xs = []
        for nbr in get_nbrs(g, node):
            if nbr not in _disc:
                _x, _disc = helper(_disc, nbr)
                _xs.append(_x)
        return combiner(node, _xs), _disc

    disc = set()
    xs = []
    for v in vertices(g):
        if v not in disc:
            x, disc = helper(disc, v)
            xs.append(x)
    return xs
```

Of course it would work without the underscores, but I’ve heard it’s bad hygiene to shadow variables like that. The underscores are ugly and invite mistakes (arguably moreso than the shadowing itself).

Comment: Can you give examples of mistakes that using underscores may invite? If using completely different variable names is out of the question(?) and you'd rather not shadow the names with or without an underscore then perhaps moving the helper function outside the parent function could be considered, though this would mean manually passing all the vars as args

Comment: Using an underscore in a parameter name usually indicates that the parameter isn't used in the implementation (i.e. it's only there to satisfy a particular signature).  Using it this way is confusing.

Comment: @IainShelvington Using the underscore version when you mean the non-underscore version and vice-versa is a potential mistake. I'm thinking of the general case when I have an operation I want to repeat, internal to a function, and the variables on which I perform the operation naturally would have the same names as their corresponding parameters in the inner function. Maybe this case doesn't come up super-often in Python, maybe people handle it in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest just eliminating the unnecessary variables rather than coming up with schemes for giving them similar-but-different names.  In particular, `disc` doesn't need to get passed as a parameter and returned because there's only ever one `disc` (and it's mutable, so it never needs to get reassigned).  Once you get rid of all the extra passing/reassignment of `disc` you can also get rid of `x` inside the loops, and you can get rid of `xs` by making it a list comprehension:

```
def graph_fold(g: Graph,
               combiner: Callable[[Node_key, List], Any]) -> List:
    """Equivalent to forming a depth-first forest and
    mapping `fold-tree combiner` over
    the trees"""
    disc = set()

    def helper(node: Node_key) -> Any:
        disc.add(node)
        return combiner(node, [
            helper(nbr)
            for nbr in get_nbrs(g, node)
            if nbr not in disc
        ])

    return [
        helper(v)
        for v in vertices(g)
        if v not in disc
    ]
```

I'd also suggest giving `helper` a better name than `helper` (unfortunately I don't have a good enough understanding of what this code is actually doing to come up with a descriptive name).